# Angular2 use 2 Sidebars with routing

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, sidebar

if i have two sidebars with content , how do i use routing if its in the same hierarchy but not in the same element?

i think i cant use another `<router-outlet>` for both Sidebars since they are not the same and shouldnt display the same content
i cant figure out how i should get this working.

i would like just to have a sidebar on the left with a container showing Content A and on the right sidebar a container showing Content B

this is my app.routing.ts file

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/Roulette', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Roulette', component: RouletteComponent },
    { path: 'Jackpot', component: JackpotComponent },
    { path: 'Dice', component: DiceComponent },
    { path: 'Crash', component: CrashComponent },
    { path: 'Bingo', component: BingoComponent },
    { path: 'Chat', component: ChatComponent },
    { path: 'Account', component: AccountComponent }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may consider using named router-outlet

```
<router-outlet name="awesome" ></router-outlet>
```

and in routes use it like below,

```
{
  path: 'Chat',
  component: ChatComponent,
  outlet: 'awesome'
}
```

Read more about  [Displaying multiple routes in named outlets here.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#named-outlets)

Check this [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNFulaAlv14B7IYzqzFo?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: wait that actually gonna work ?  so i can use 3 outlets in the same component.html ? wow nice thanks man i will try it out now and give you feedback if i got it working. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Prototype, Added a Plunker example, Cheers!!

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks alot! saved my day  and alot of headbreaking time:)